# fread: Opened file ok but couldn't obtain file size

Tags: r, data.table

I have a problem using R with the function `fread`.
When I try to read a particular file I get the following message:

```
Opened file ok but couldn't obtain its size:
```

Searching on the web I've found the part of the code that generates that message (in the fread.c file), but I don't know how to explain this problem:

```
if (fstat(fd,&stat_buf) == -1) {close(fd); error("Opened file ok but couldn't obtain file size: %s", fnam);}
```

The command `file.info(my_file)` can see the file size correctly. Furthermore the function `read.table` can read the file without problems.

I'm using R on a Debian machine and the file I want to read is on a mounted cifs remote disk. I think that this can be a part of the problem. In fact if I copy the file on a local path I can read the file using fread without problems.
Why `read.table` works and `fread` doesn't work?
Is it a problem of the file on the mounted disk or is it a problem of the fread function?
Any idea?

Comment: Can you share the file, or a file that replicates the problem please?

Comment: Even a simple file like
    `a b\n1 2\n3 4`
do the job.
I think that fread doesn't like the fact that the file is on a share, rather than the structure of the file itself.

Comment: It sounds like deliberate behavior from the function (demanding that size can be read from C even if it can be read from R's file.info), but maybe you'll want to report it https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support (which requires installing the development version of the package, etc)